# Debian 7 cannot connect to the Internet

Tags: linux, debian

I have installed Debian7 and I've applied the whole configurations about IP, DNS, Gateway and I have added on the browser the proxy exceptions but i can't even make a ping to google, on my LAN it works ok, but my problem is just to try to connect to internet.

Comment: I dont know, how can i know such info?

Comment: Because Tech Support gave me some exceptions to add to my browser because sometimes it doesn't enter to internet because of the proxy.

Comment: All i got is ping: unknown host for any website

Answer (score 0):

Can you ping your gateway?

What you are describing fits an incorrect gateway in that you can get LAN access, but as soon as you want to contact a resource (website etc) outside your local network - it fails.  This would imply that your gateway (route out to the net) is unavailable.

If other machines can get out to the net but this one cant - it's probably your gateway.

Failing that, if you have setup a proxy server and don't have a proxy (which frm the way you describe your issue, you don't) - then the traffic will try to find a proxy server to route through and this won't work.

If you don't actually have a dedicated proxy and get to the internet through a normal router, disable your proxy on the Debian PC, remove the proxy exceptions and try again.

Comment: Yes, i can ping my gateway and i can also ping the LAN. My problems just with internet. If all pcs (on windows) can get on the internet and this pc (debian) cant, what is wrong on my proxy? I have cleaned up the exceptions from the browser but with no solution.